# Envío y recepción de paquetes de audio por VoIP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, programación-funcional

Estoy realizando un sistema para hacer y recibir llamadas usando la librería *"SIP.NET"* de *independentsoft*, pero al parecer esta librería no cuenta con este apartado de la recepción y envío de paquetes de audio, por lo que no se escuchan las llamadas. El soporte de la librería me comentó que tenía que añadir lo del RTP (Protocolo de Transporte de Tiempo Real).

Investigando, encontré información de este protocolo, que es el que permite la entrada y salida de audio, pero no veo cómo integrarlo a mi sistema. Ya tengo todo el funcionamiento principal de hacer llamadas y recibirla, pero como he mencionado, no se escuchan.

Si es posible, quisiera que este apartado no use la librería Ozeki.

Nota: El sistema se está desarrollando en C# (escritorio).

Comment: https://dev.office.com/Skype/sdks#skypeForBusiness, Aquí te dejo la opción de Skype y sus formas de implementar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar lo revisare

Answer (score 0):

Deberias analizar el ejemplo de codigo que proporciona la libreria `SIP.NET`

[sip tutorial](http://www.independentsoft.de/sip/tutorial/index.html)

en este veo que tiene ejemplos para realizar/recibir llamadas. Fijate por ejemplo el codigo del `Invite` alli comenta:

> The Invite method is used to establish media sessions between user agents. In the example below see how Bob makes phone call to Alice. Bob sends following session description for this call.

creo que es lo que buscas

Comment: Te agradezco tu comentario, y te comento he revisado todos los ejemplos que proporciona la pagina, e inclusive estuve comunicándome con los de soporte, ellos mismo me dijeron esto: You need additional API (RTP protocol API and codecs). de hecho en los ejemplos tiene lo de Media y agregas algunas configuraciones y creí que eso seria mas que suficiente para que el audio se escuchara pero no fue asi.

Comment: no puede pedirle al soporte que sean mas especificos respecto a que codec hacen referencia, porque una cosa es una api que supone ser una libreria que debas usar en tu codigo y otra muy distinta es un codec la cual hace referencia a un driver que se instala, son cosas muy distintas